# Different ads for every page on wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress, ads, sidebar

I want to implement on a magazine Wordpress theme a way to put different ads on every page on the sidebar... couldn't find a plugin for this or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look into this plugin:

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/adrotate/

I use it for many websites and it is very good.